# Facebook Access Token Expiring Prematurely

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-authentication

I recently disabled offline_access as requested by Facebook's 1 October breaking change, and have re-authorised all linked services that suddenly terminated on 1 October. The access tokens I received all indicated an expiry date of "never" according to Facebook's debug page, and they worked flawlessly for a few days.

However at some random point over the past few days, some seem to have be discontinued without warning. I have tried using the debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it just says it cannot recognise the token (Error Parsing URL/Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.) It does not indicate a problem like a changed password or something similar.

I know that without an extension, tokens are normally issued for 2 hours, but these worked for days. Aren't tokens meant to last for 60 days without refreshing them?

Or do I need to start refreshing them daily using the valid keys I currently have?

Comment: I think the problem is sorted now. We were truncating the access codes :( Not sure if it's resolved for sure, but we'll know in about a week.

Answer (score 1):

When you (re)authorise an app the token only lasts for a couple of hours, you have to do a token exchange to make it last for 60 days.

But Facebook do randomly kill tokens... I've had my own expire with the "User changed password" message - when I most certainly didn't.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried various exchanges and nothing seems to make a difference.

Here are the steps I follow:

1. Call the https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth endpoint
2. Receive a "code" variable back
3. Call the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token endpoint sending in the "code" variable
4. Call the https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token endpoint again with the resulting "access_token" variable, but specifying grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token= params
5. The access token it returns is identical to what I get in step 3

Answer (score 0):

Use some random point over the past few days, some seem to have be discontinued without warning. It does not indicate a problem like a changed password or something similar. this will work and the token works